# How to get a list of param in a Map from @RequestParam in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have this endpoint (with all irrelevant removed) and like to see how to get the list of file names directly from the Param Map:

- the first @RequestParam is to make the "file" param required,
- the second @RequestParam is to get all param into the map instead of individually.

i.e.: http://localhost:8080/files?file=first&file=second&file=third

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/files",
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFiles(@RequestParam(value = "file",
                                   required = true) String[] files,
                     @RequestParam Map<String, Object> params) {
    for (String file : files) { // this works, all get printed
        logger.info("file: " + file);
    }

    // this, however, only gives the first entry not the whole list
    //
    logger.info("params.get(file): " + params.get("file")); 
}
```

Comment: The question is : how could you define a key for each value in your map? it seems a little difficult as your files come from a request.

Answer (score 0):

A map *cannot have multiple values with the same key*. Since multiple parameters have the same name (`file`), only one value is kept.

To deal with queries with multiple param having the same key, use `MultiValueMap<String, Object>`. A multivaluemap is

> an Extension of the Map interface that stores multiple values.